# Classe com duas funções while executando somente uma

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
def reward_colector(self, quit=None):
        if self.follow == True:
            while True:
                self.btn_reward_status = False
                try:
                    self.btn_reward = self.nav.find_element_by_xpath(
                        "//button[@aria-label='Claim Bonus']"
                    )
                    self.btn_reward_status = True
                except Exception as e:
                    print('Objeto não encontrado')
                    sleep(300)
                if self.btn_reward_status == True:
                    self.btn_reward.click()
                    print(f'Reward redeemed, Current points: {self.points.text} {self.streamer}')
                if quit == True:
                    return False

    def msg_sender(self, msg, quit=None):
        while True:
            twitch_input = self.nav.find_element_by_xpath("//textarea[@placeholder='Send a message']")
            twitch_input.send_keys(msg)
            btn_send = self.nav.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@data-a-target='chat-send-button']")
            btn_send.click()
            sleep(300)
        if quit == True:
            return False




if __name__ == '__main__':
    threading.Thread(target=twitch.msg_sender('Testando meu bot :)')).start()
    twitch.reward_colector()
```

já tentei com threads ele executa sempre o primeiro, mas o segundo n, eles estão dentro de uma classe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para o parâmetro `target` do construtor da classe `Thread`, você deve passar **uma função** que vai ser chamada para execução em paralelo. Do jeito que o código está escrito, você está chamando a função `twitch.msg_sender` com o argumento `'Testando meu bot :)'` e passando o valor de retorno dela como `target`. Como essa função fica presa em um loop, ela nunca retorna, então o seu código fica travado tentando encontrar o valor que vai ser passado para o parâmetro `target`.

O código correto seria

```py
threading.Thread(target=twitch.msg_sender, args=['Testando meu bot :)'])
twitch.reward_collector()
```

Note que, dessa vez, o `target` é a própria função e não o valor de retorno dela. Note também que o argumento `args` também é passado, para que o construtor da classe `Thread` saiba quais argumentos passar para o seu `target` quando ele chamá-lo.

Comment: vlw irmão, agr funcionou certinho :)